# sql server management studio enable encryption

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I see that i can manage encryption through the option:
right click database->tasks->manage database encryption

I see two options using asymmetric key or certificate as shown below
[image]

but i don't see an upload option of the key or certficate .

Can somebody please let me know how to upload a certificate and enable the encryption?

Thank you

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS version included, and have a look first a [MS Doc about encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-server-certificates-and-asymmetric-keys?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 2):

SSMS GUI expects you to Create your server certificate before you mange database encryption.

Ref: [CREATE CERTIFICATE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-certificate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Once you create the server certificate you you will be able to chose from the drop down box.

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE testencryptioncert   
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'pGFD4bb925DGvbd2439587y'  
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Testing Encryption',   
   EXPIRY_DATE = '20201031';  
GO
```

Now the above certificate will show up in the drop down list of the GUI.

[image]